# Print/debug cause of upload error in PHP

Tags: php

I'm a PHP newbie and have written a script to process form uploads. It works for small files(less than 1Mb). However when I try to upload an ~4Mb pdf file it returns an error message. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I ran php_info, got the value of "upload_tmp_dir" and set it to a directory owned by the apache process(www-data)

My client-side code is

```
<form action="upper.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="myFile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Upper.php contains

```
define("UPLOAD_DIR", "/var/www/html/upload/");

if (!empty($_FILES["myFile"])) {
    $myFile = $_FILES["myFile"];

    if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo "Error is " . $myFile["error"];
        //echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
        exit;
    }    

    $name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);

    // don't overwrite an existing file
    $i = 0;
    $parts = pathinfo($name);
    while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
        $i++;
        $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
    }

    // preserve file from temporary directory
    $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"], UPLOAD_DIR . $name);
    if (!$success) {
        echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";
        exit;
    }

    // set proper permissions on the new file
    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);
}
```

Comment: its not the issue of folder owner , it's a issue with your php file upload limit , you should increase your upload limit inside php.ini

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP change the maximum upload file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have wrong config in you php.ini file.

You need to set

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

its already described here: [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 1):

You ned to set values in php.in file. 
Open the file,
Find `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` lines. 
Change this two value. (M= MB)

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 20M
; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 20M
```

Restart the sever for effect. 
**Note:**

1. You can set any number. But not use any decimal value.
2. Open the php.ini file in NOTEPAD. Don't user wordpad or any word processor.